# Adjusting days of the week depending on the input

Tags: php, mysql

I want to set event to the input day. For example, if a user inserts a query on Tuesday and the schedule of the subject is Friday, how can I create an event that will be activated every Friday?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM subjects where day='$day' and starttime='$starttime' and endtime='$endtime' and yearlevel='$yearlevel' ";
$result =$conn->query($sql);
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
if ($row_cnt < 1) { 

    $add="INSERT INTO subjects (subjects, day, starttime, endtime, yearlevel)
            VALUES ('$subjects','$day','$oper','$oper1','$yearlevel')";
    $result2 =$conn->query($add);


$event="CREATE EVENT {$subjects}attendance ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK
 STARTS 'CURDATE() 06:00:00'
 ";
}
```

Comment: Where are capturing `schedule_date` or `input_date`. How the program should understand differentiate your input date and schedule date?

Comment: the input is not on date but on days it is on the variable $day which accept monday to friday..... its a schedule of a subject in university which is monday to friday... the problem is how can i create an event on the day depending on which the user input... for example $day=monday; that is encoded on a friday day! or any day except the day it self. i just want to set a weekly event on the day depending what the user inputted, my problem is on creating an event depending on the day input of the user which should reoccur on the day of the input

Comment: Just passing a day name won't work. You should use a *base date* with respect to which your could would find date of occurrence of next `'monday'` or `'friday'` and use the same in your event scheduler.

Comment: is there a way to convert the next date of the day of the input depending on the given,  which is the input in name of the day and the data('l') in which the day of the data that is inputted. please provide me a better work around on this thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to input a base date, then take `current_date` as base date. Check whether it is `monday` or `friday`. If not fid what next date does `monday` or `friday` fall on. And then use the same in your Event.